# Visual Basics, Store comboBox value in variable

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I want to save the comboBox value in a variable.But whenever I change the comboBox value the value gets set is null, and the selected index shows as '-1'.Below is my code.

```
Private Sub SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim form As CreateEvalForm = New CreateEvalForm //windows Form
    Dim str As String = form.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
    MessageBox.Show(str)                            //shows null
    Dim openingId As Integer = Val(form.ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: SelectedIndex is an integer, not a string. And ComboBox1.SelectedItem is a little bit better than ComboBox1.Text normally.

Comment: @muffi, `SelectedItem` is not better than `Text`. They are both good for their intended purpose. `Text` specifically gets the text displayed in the control for the selected item while `SelectedItem` gets the item itself.  Which you should use depends on which of those you want.  If you have added `Strings` to the drop-down list then the two will return the same thing, although `Text` is type `String` and `SelectedItem` is type `Object`. If you have set the `DisplayMember` then they are very much not the same thing.

Comment: Of course you get no selected item.  You're handling an event of a control on the current form and then, in the event handler, you create a brand new form and access a control on it.  That form hasn't even been displayed so of course nothing has been selected on it.  Get rid of the code that creates the new form and then access the `ComboBox` on the current form.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yep that worked.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim str As String = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
    MessageBox.Show(str)
    Dim openingId As Integer = Val(ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Does this work? But if you wanted a value from the combobox's selected value, you should try the following:

```
dim openingId as Integer = Val(comboBox1.SelectedValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim form As CreateEvalForm = New CreateEvalForm //windows Form
```

With this line you are creating a new form, so the combobox on that new form will be new as well and will not have a selected index.

You can just use the combobox in this way:

```
Dim str As String = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
```

or

```
Dim str As String = Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
```